# Simulate event resize

Tags: javascript, dom

Hi I'm using DOM2 and added a few event listeners "resize" for `window` object, using `addEventListener`. And now I need to simulate this action (window.resize) to call event listeners that are attached to the `window` object. How can I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following should work:

```
var resizeEvent = new Event('resize');

window.dispatchEvent(resizeEvent);
```

[Simple (ridiculously so) demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/smqw5cps/).

References:

- [Creating and triggering (JavaScript) events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).
- [`Event()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event).