# How to identify if css property on element is in 'px' or 'vw' unit?

Tags: javascript, css

Want to know if applied css on an element e.g. width is a pixel unit or related to viewport because `window.getComputedStyle` always give value in pixels.

Even tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36460652/1232490) to identify percentage, but does not work in case of identified 'em', 'vw', 'rem' units.

Note: Not asking for inline styling on element.

Comment: really interesting question. i hope someone will find a way to do it

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Comment: @torazaburo want to change property value keeping the unit same. Thing is, I want to do different operations according to different property unit.

Comment: Please give a specific example. What kind of "different operations"?

Comment: @torazaburo want to automate increase of width of any element without breaking responsiveness using javascript.

Comment: We really need a more specific example of what you want to do. Under what circumstances do you want to increase the width, in a way that is expressed how, and how would this differ depending on the units in which the width was originally specified? Do you want to increase it by a particular number of pixels, or a particular percentage?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try to simulate a resize event (changing the `window.innerWidth`) and check if you get the same result from `window.getComputedStyle`

[Simulate event resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28926898/simulate-event-resize)

Comment: this won't work for sure. May be some combination of operations might work. Resizing is possible for popup windows, main window can not be resized by any js method.